# ¿Por qué el resultado de una función se asigna a múltiples variables a la vez?

Tags: python

Tengo este programa y no entiendo por qué en la última parte iguala la def con repeticiones y nombres:

```
def lista_nombres():
            nombres = []
            ok = False
            repeticiones = 0
            while ok == False:
                x = input("Ingresa un nombre o 0 para terminar: ")
                if x == "0":
                    ok == True
                    break
                if x in nombres:
                    print("El nombre ya está en la lista.")
                    repeticiones = repeticiones + 1
                nombres.append(x)

            return nombres, repeticiones

nombres, repeticiones = lista_nombres()
print("La lista es: ", nombres)
print( repeticiones/len(nombres))
print(repeticiones)
```

Comment: Hola, mejora la calidad de la pregunta y agrega mas información.También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Python un función puede retornar una tupla, que es un conjunto de valores empaquetados en un único objeto. Veamoslo de forma conceptual:

```
def lista_nombres():
  return ("Valor1", "Valor2")
```

Tienes una función que va a retornar una tupla de dos valores "Valor1" y "Valor2". El retorno de la función puedes "desempaquetarlo" automáticamente haciendo:

```
v1, v2 = lista_nombres()
```

En este caso asignas dos variables directamente del retorno de una función (eventualmente podrían ser más valores). Como dato adicional, si alguno de los valores retornados por la función no te interesan, los puedes ignorar con el caracter `_`:

```
v1, _ = lista_nombres()
```