# ¿Cómo obtener con Python el listado de carpetas existentes en una ruta del tipo \\192.168.xxx.xxx?

Tags: python, python-3.x

He intentado lo típico de listar una ruta con Python mediante os.walk, pero no me devuelve el listado.

```
import os

ruta = r'\\192.168.44.3'

listado = os.walk(ruta)

for root, folders, files in listado:
    for folder in folders:
        print(folder)
    print(100*"=")

print("FIN")
```

**Al correr el código anterior solamente aparece el print("FIN").**

No se si tengo que hacerlo de manera diferente para este caso en el que lo que quiero es obtener el listado de las carpetas del servidor interno de la organización en la que trabajo, soy novato en Python y posiblemente lo esté haciendo mal para este caso en particular.
Les agradezco desde ya sus aportes.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: No se puede, que yo sepa, recorrer todas las carpetas existentes en un servidor de disco desde su raiz, pero sí se puede desde cada una de las carpetas compartidas en el raiz. Es decir, por ejemplo, si tú sabes que en tu disco de red hay una carpeta compartida llamada "Documentos", entonces te funcionará: `os.walk(r"\\192.168.44.3\Documentos")`. Pero lo mismo te ocurre desde un CMD. Si intentas `DIR \\192.168.44.3` te va a dar error, pero si lo haces a la carpeta Documents funcionará. Otra solución es montar la unidad de red en una letra, y hacer `os.walk("Y:")` por ejemplo.

Comment: Muchas gracias.
Así lo he estado haciendo, pero me había entrado la curiosidad de saber si se podía de la otra forma, es decir teniendo la dirección del servidor poder listar todas las carpetas que se encuentran en él en el primer nivel siguiente a la raíz y así saber que cuantas carpetas existen y los nombres, así como su tamaño.
De todas formas tu respuesta igual me ayudó.
De nuevo muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que `\\192.168.xxx.xxx` [no es una carpeta "real"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46180783/12400721), solo la usa
el explorador de Windows para mostrar las carpetas compartidas que tiene una máquina
en red.

Si quieres obtener el listado de carpetas de cada carpeta compartida puedes
usar la función NetShareEnum del módulo [win32net](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) para obtener una lista de
las carpetas compartidas y luego usar os.walk con cada una (advertencia: código no
probado):

```
import win32net

remotehost = '192.168.1.4'

shares, _, _ = win32net.NetShareEnum(remotehost, 0)

for share in shares:
    for _, folders, _ in os.walk(rf'\\{remotehost}\{share}'):
        for folder in folders:
            print(folder)
    print(100*"=")

print("FIN")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no tenía idea del porque no podía obtener la lista de carpetas.

Comment: No he probado tu código, pero lo tendré pendiente.
De nuevo gracias.
Una duda.
¿Qué significa la línea **shares, _, _ = win32net.NetShareEnum(remotehost, 0)**?
Soy novato en Python y no he visto esa sintaxis con los **_**.
Te agradecería me aclares la duda.

Comment: @AlfredoNoboaC No se a que parte en especial de la linea te refieres pero aca hay un ejemplo de una [función que devuelve una tupla y como se "desempaqueta"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/179991/166122), o sino de [un módulo y como se accede a las funciones que define](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/modules.html).